# How to remove \n���� from a sentence in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to remove \n���� from a sentence in biquery. I have used the following query  REGEXP_REPLACE(Sentence, r'([^\p{ASCII}]+)', '')  AS Senetnce. It is removing only the question marks. How do I remove \n also? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below

```
select regexp_replace(Sentence, r'\n|[^\p{ASCII}]+', '')
```

if apply to your Question's title `How to remove \n���� from a sentence in bigquery` - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mikhali. It is still giving me \n

Comment: I do not know the regex version used here, but in C# we would need to use something like `"\\n|..."`, the backslash needs to be doubled within a string.